# Flutter flame How to show a emerging animation

Tags: flutter, animation, flame

I want to show a fancy entering animation, like enemy jumps out of a black hole, comprised of multiple images in a png file. Once that's done, the enemy will show the idle image sprite.

I thought about SpriteAnimationGroupComponent to have something like

```
enum PlayerState { entering, idle, disappearing }
```

but the problem is I can not tell when the entering animation is finished so that I can transfer it to idle state.

Also thought about Effect but it doesn't work with images.

Is there an ideal approach for it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `onComplete` callback to the `entering` animation and set the state of the player to `idle`.

Something like this:

```dart
final yourComponent = SpriteAnimationGroupComponent(...);
yourComponent.animations[PlayerState.entering].onComplete = 
  () => yourComponent.current = PlayerState.idle;
```

Comment: that's what I thought too. Thanks!